# GHC Haskell Compiler for AARCH64

Tags: cross-compilation, haskell

I recently bought a Odroid C2 (AARCH64), but I need o execute Haskell programs on it.

There is no GHC (Haskell-Compiler) binary for this architecture on the web.

But I also failed to cross compile GHC

Maybe someone can CrossCompile GHC for AARCH64 for me or know an other, easier way?

Comment: This may be useful: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/maintainers/releases/#setting-up-an-arm-vm-for-releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no GHC (Haskell-Compiler) binary for this architecture on the web (at least I haven't found anything).

What distro are you using? It seems to me it's in the repos for both Debian and Ubuntu since Jessie and Trusty.

> Could you give help regards ArchlinuxARM

Sorry, no

> or could you give the link to the Package in the Deb/Ubu repo?

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/ghc

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ghc

(note that Debian/ubuntu call the architecture arm64)

Comment: Archlinux -> https://archlinuxarm.org/

Comment: Could you give help regards ArchlinuxARM or could you give the link to the Package in the Deb/Ubu repo?

Comment: There is no package for AARCH64

Comment: But this debian package doesn't contain `runhaskell` command ...

Comment: Looks like it does in stretch and sid but not in jessie.